# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python-3.x

```
def reduce(self,a,b):
   self.dividend =a
   self.divisor = b
   if(a != 0 and b != 0 ):
      if(a > b):
         self.dividend = a
         self.divisor = b
      else:
          self.dividendo = a
          self.divisor = b

      while(a % b != 0 ):
          r = a % b
          a = b
          b = r
      return b
```

Eu tenho esta parte do progama, em que depois aparece o erro seguinte:

> while(a % b != 0 ):
>   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

o que devo mudar ?

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre porque em alguma parte do seu código a função `reduce` esta sendo chamada com o parâmetro `a` sendo um `string`. Nesse caso o python interpreta o operador `%` não como `mod` mas como [operador de formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting).

Teste o tipo dos parâmetros no início da função.

```
def reduce (self, a, b):
    # validar os parametros
    try:
        a = int(a)
        b = int(b)
    except ValueError:
        if isinstance(a, int):
            erro = b
        else:
            erro = a
        raise ValueError('%s nao pode ser convertido em um numero' % erro)

    # valores validados prosseguir normalmente
    self.dividend = a
    self.divisor = b
    if(a != 0 and b != 0 ):
        if(a > b):
            self.dividend = a
            self.divisor = b
        else:
            self.dividendo = a
            self.divisor = b

    while(a % b != 0 ):
        r = a % b
        a = b
        b = r

    return b
```